# Use 'add_theme_support' instead of 'add_custom_image_header' In WordPress 3.4

Tags: functions, deprecation

I am debugging my theme using [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin, which is showing me this error (among a few others):

> Notice: `add_custom_image_header` is deprecated since version 3.4! Use `add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args )` instead.

Okay, clearly, it says I need to [use this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Custom_Header) instead of [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_image_header). The question is, `add_custom_image_header` has three parameters, namely:

- $header_callback
- $admin_header_callback
- $admin_image_div_callback

How do I represent them in `add_theme_support` function? Like this?

```
$aahan_custom_header_args = array(
    'wp-head-callback'       => '',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => '',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $aahan_custom_header_args );
```

Also, are `wp-head-callback`, `admin-head-callback`, and `admin-preview-callback`, the exact replacements for `$header_callback`, `$admin_header_callback`, and `$admin_image_div_callback` respectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read [Updating Custom Backgrounds and Custom Headers for WordPress 3.4](http://make.wordpress.org/themes/2012/04/06/updating-custom-backgrounds-and-custom-headers-for-wordpress-3-4/).

### Custom Headers

Old method:

> ```
> // Define default header image constant
> define( 'HEADER_IMAGE', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/headers/default.jpg' );
> // Define header image width constant
> define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', 1000 );
> // Define header image height constant
> define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', 198 );
> // Define header text constant
> define( 'NO_HEADER_TEXT', false );
> // Define header text color constant
> define( 'HEADER_TEXTCOLOR', '000' );
> // Turn on random header image rotation by default.
> // Requires HEADER_IMAGE to be null
> add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array( 'random-default' => true ) );
>
> // Add Theme support
> add_custom_image_header( $wphead_cb, $adminhead_cb, $adminpreview_cb );
> ```

New method:

> ```
> add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
>     // Header image default
>     'default-image'         => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/headers/default.jpg',
>     // Header text display default
>     'header-text'           => false,
>     // Header text color default
>     'default-text-color'        => '000',
>     // Header image width (in pixels)
>     'width'             => 1000,
>     // Header image height (in pixels)
>     'height'            => 198,
>     // Header image random rotation default
>     'random-default'        => false,
>     // Template header style callback
>     'wp-head-callback'      => $wphead_cb,
>     // Admin header style callback
>     'admin-head-callback'       => $adminhead_cb,
>     // Admin preview style callback
>     'admin-preview-callback'    => $adminpreview_cb
> ) );
> ```

Again: that was easy, wasn't it?

Just to clarify, here are the old-constant/new-array-key equivalents:

> ```
> HEADER_IMAGE       => 'default-image'
> HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH  => 'width'
> HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT => 'height'
> NO_HEADER_TEXT      => 'header-text'
> HEADER_TEXTCOLOR    => 'default-text-color'
> ```

All of the same callbacks are supported, exactly as before.

For reference, here is the complete defaults array:

> ```
> $defaults = array(
>     'default-image' => '',
>     'random-default' => false,
>     'width' => 0,
>     'height' => 0,
>     'flex-height' => false,
>     'flex-width' => false,
>     'default-text-color' => '',
>     'header-text' => true,
>     'uploads' => true,
>     'wp-head-callback' => '',
>     'admin-head-callback' => '',
>     'admin-preview-callback' => '',
> );
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that was very very clear indeed. Just to confirm what I am doing is right, are `wp-head-callback`, `admin-head-callback`, and `admin-preview-callback` in the new function, the exact replacements for `$header_callback`, `$admin_header_callback`, and `$admin_image_div_callback` respectively?

Comment: Yes. Those are the exact analogs. It was designed to be straightforward to port from the old implementation to the new. (Thankfully :) )